# how to create a salesforce rollup field thats not on a master record in pro edtion

Tags: account, fields, master-detail, roll-up-summary, group-by-rollup

I have a object called key account with all the accounts that belong to this key account connected - the connected accounts have a sales total field which i what to add into a total on the Key account, i cant use a roll up and the key account is not a master record??
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Rollup Helper](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI) app. Since you can't use code yourself, you're limited strictly to whatever you can find that supports Professional Edition.